# CSS selector not working as expected in Angular 2 application with 3rd party library

Tags: angular, css-selectors

I am trying to put a slider inside an Angular component but I cannot get the styles to work properly. No matter what CSS selectors I have tried it just won't find anything to do with the slider, but it does successfully style other elements so I know the CSS file is being used. The css is below:

```
/*This selector works*/
h1 {
  background: red;
}

#slider19 {
  margin: 10px;
}

#slider19 .slider-track {
    background: #2eb82e;
}

#slider19 .slider-selection {
    background: #2eb82e;
}

#slider19 .slider-handle {
    background: #040404;
}
```

I've tested the exact same CSS in a vanilla javascript application and it works as expected, and if I add the CSS file as a link in the index.html it works.

The slider is a [bootstrap-slider](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap-slider) and a Plunker which demonstrates the issue can be found [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/KDOdafjOKFef4feoXCdb?p=preview)

Comment: Look at `/deep/`.

Comment: FIrst, you're using a beta version of angular 2, instead of using the latest, stable version. Second, Due to component encapsulation, the CSS is rewritten by angular to something like `#slider19[_ngcontent-bla-1] {
  margin: 10px;
}`. That would work fine if the HTML was generated by Angular, but it's not. You're using jQuery to generate it instead. Start by using the latest stable version of Angular, then try finding or writing an ANgular-based slider, then, if really needed, disable view encapsulation on that component: https://plnkr.co/edit/GyqZ75dDn5r6xHQiALRS?p=preview

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for that it cleared up a lot. I've decided to write my own slider but I'll accept your comment as the answer if you want to post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you're using a beta version of angular 2, instead of using the latest, stable version.

Second, due to component encapsulation, the CSS is rewritten by angular to something like

```
#slider19[_ngcontent-bla-1] { margin: 10px; }.
```

That would work fine if the HTML was generated by Angular, but it's not. You're using jQuery to generate it instead.

Start by using the latest stable version of Angular, then try finding or writing an Angular-based slider, then, if really needed, disable view encapsulation on that component. Here is [an example](https://plnkr.co/edit/GyqZ75dDn5r6xHQiALRS?p=preview).